# Regex to get correct string output

Tags: regex

I am trying to get `RaisePropertyChanged(DominSelectors)` from below text using regex.

```
base.RaisePropertyChanged<IEnumerable<DominSearcherViewModel>>(Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<DominSearcherViewModel>>>(Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this, typeof(TestViewModel)), (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(typeof(TestViewModel).GetMethod("get_DominSelectors").MethodHandle)), new ParameterExpression[0]));
```

i have tried below regex but i am not getting correct result:-

```
.*?(RaisePropertyChanged).*?\\(.*?\\(.*?\\(.*?\\(.*?\\(.*?\\(.*?\\(.*?\\(.*?(\\().*?(DominSelectors).*?\\).*?\\).*?\\).*?\\).*?(\\))(;)
```

Wrong Result :- `RaisePropertyChanged("get_DominSelectors");`

Right Result :- `RaisePropertyChanged(DominSelectors);`

**EDIT** :  get_DominSelectors is not fix word i can have any word starting as get_ABC,get_Xyz. i wanted only ABC and Xyz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
.*(RaisePropertyChanged).*((?<=get_)\w+(?="\))).*;
```

Replace:

```
\1(\2);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EgXlcD/14

Regex:

`.*` - Match 0 or more of any characters

`(?<=get_)` - Positive lookbehind for `get_`

`(?="\))` - Positive look ahead for `")`

Comment: DominSelectors is not fix , at that place any string could be there, how to make that?

Comment: @VarunJain Can you include the other example as well in your question?

Comment: @VarunJain Check. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

`\w*(RaisePropertyChanged).*(?:get_)(\w+(?="\))).*;`

Capture Group 1: `RaisePropertyChanged`

Capture Group 2: `whatever_word_string` after `get_` and before `")`

Comment: `\w+` will make more sense after `get_` instead of `\w*`